# Remove a row from a table to another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two tables: Admin and Worker. they have the same arguments (email, password, etc).

I tried to remove the row that contains the email: "foo@example.com" from Worker table into the Admin table (and delete it from the Worker Table).

I tried the next thing:

```
@email = 'foo@example.com'
@row_email_deleted = Worker.find_by_email(@email)
Admin.add(@row_email_deleted)
@row_email_deleted.destroy
```

but it doesn't work :/

Can someone help me to fix my problem?

Comment: you have two tables with similar structure? may be you should try STI (single table inheritance)

Comment: `it doesn't work` heck, it doesn't mean anything... btw what the `add` mthod?

Comment: I define it by the device. I want two kind of users: admins and workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with apneadiving, I don't know what the 'add' method is composed of.  That and not a lot of detail on exactly what isn't working makes it hard to know why it's not working.  That said, ignoring all of that, I would do something like this:

```
Worker.transaction do
  @email = 'foo@example.com'
  @worker = Worker.find_by_email(@email)
  Admin.create(@worker.attributes.reject{|k,v| %w[id].include?(k)}) 
  @worker.destroy
end
```

- Wrap the whole thing in a transaction to ensure that you you don't delete the worker but not add the admin.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html
- The 'reject...' bit is to remove any worker attributes that you don't want in Admin (or that can't be passed en-masse).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@email = 'alon@gmail.com'
@worker = Worker.find_by_email(@email)
@new_admin = @worker.becomes Admin
@new_admin.save
@worker.destroy
```

But I propose you should try to refactor to STI e.g.: http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance